# SQL Server: Select all rows where if any one of the 4 columns has a value of 'N'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

This is my data in table.

```
**ID    webLoad transmitted transmissionRcvd    ackRcvd**
   1       Y       Y              N                N
   2       Y       N              Y                N
   3       Y       Y              Y                Y
   4       N       Y              Y                N
   5       Y       N              N                Y
   6       N       Y              Y                Y
   7       Y       Y              Y                Y
   8       Y       Y              Y                N
   9       Y       Y              Y                Y
```

I want to be able to select all rows where if any one of the above 4 columns has a value of 'N'

so the rows in result should be ID=1,2,4,5,6,8

**NOTE:** In some cases the input will not be same for all columns. I mean there could be a case that parameter for webLoad will null or 'Y' and 'N' for others. same can be happened to any one these columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where 'N' in (webLoad, transmitted, transmissionRcvd, ackRcvd)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE webload = 'N' 
OR transmitted = 'N'
OR transmissionRcvd = 'N'
OR ackRcvd = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableName a
Where 
a.webLoad ='N' or 
a.transmitted ='N' or 
a.transmissionRcvd ='N' or 
a.ackRcvd ='N'
```